# Increment a value in mysql table column dynamically

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table column (runs) which holds an integer, I want to increment it by another dynamic value (1,2,3,4,5) using an update query on click of a button. How should I do that?

(Without retrieving the original value from that table column, is there any direct way to increment the value, not like AUTO_INCREMENT since it does it using a static value)

Comment: To increment something by some amount you need to know both the values. So you have to access the original value. I don't know any feature of mysql doing dynamic increment without accessing the original value.

Comment: Digvijay is right. if you want to update then there is no need to know the original value. Not clear what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I want to increment a column value dynamically, without accessing the original value,

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra: Whats the reason for not accessing the original value? Is it the DB read operation which seem to be costlier?

Comment: @DigvijayYadav Yes, Exactly.

Comment: Seems like I have no other choice.. :(

Comment: In this case I would suggest not to read/write to DB on every user click. Instead you should retrieve the value once and store them in a DS (may be an array or list). On every click you perform operations on this list and after sometime you update the DB with updated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the documentation on MySql [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and it seems you can do it with an update query like this:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;
```

where you can change 1 to any numeric value as long as col1 is also numeric.
MySql will get the initial value of col1 and add your number to it.

Even if MySql can do this, I'm guessing this also has an impact on speed, it might be faster then 2 queries, but probably needs testing to determin the differences.

When confronted with software speeds issues saving a select query for only one value it's not the key modification that you can do to optimize your app. As Digvijay Yadav suggested, you should also check other solutions, and other optimizations on to make your app faster.

another example on that page that also shows that what your are trying to do can work is :

```
UPDATE t SET id = id + 1 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

please try it and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: this one works! thanks a lot. it saves me lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

If DB interaction is the main problem then in this case I would suggest not to read/write to DB on every user click. Instead you should retrieve the value once and store them in a DS (may be an array or list). On every click you perform operations on this list and after sometime you update the DB with updated values.

Also, if you are creating and destroying the DB connections on every read/write operation then I would not suggest that. A better solution IMO is to create a DB connection when your webapp starts up and store the `connection` object in the `ServletContext` as an `attribute` as you are using servlets and JSPs.

Further if your web app is too big and has thousand of users then there are several caching techniques for improving the performance of DB.